# What is the first argument of wxIntegerValidator's constructor used for?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

When viewing the [documentation](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_integer_validator.html) you see this code:

```
{
public:
    MyDialog()
    {
        ...
        // Allow positive integers and display them with thousands
        // separators.
        wxIntegerValidator<unsigned long>
            val(&m_value, wxNUM_VAL_THOUSANDS_SEPARATOR);
        // If the variable were of type "long" and not "unsigned long"
        // we would have needed to call val.SetMin(0) but as it is,
        // this is not needed.
        // Associate it with the text control:
        new wxTextCtrl(this, ..., val);
    }
private:
    unsigned long m_value;
};
```

The address of member `m_value` is passed to the constructor, but when the associated `wxTextCtrl` responds to a `wxEVT_TEXT` the value is never changed.

Is this just used for internal work, or will the associated `wxTextCtrl` ever update this value? If it's never updated, do I need a member variable at all? I want to use the value typed into the control, so just curious if I should use the member variable that was passed to the constructor, or just convert the return value of `wxTextCtrl::GetValue()` to whatever I need.

Comment: One of the purposes of a validator is to convert a control's text to a data member for you. So yes, if you define a data member, you should use that data member, not convert the text manually. The data member is updated when the control's parent dialog is dismissed, not when the text is changed. Provided [the dialog calls the right functions](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/overview_validator.html#overview_validator_dialogs) to drive that behavior: "*For validators to work correctly, validator functions must be called at the right times during dialog initialisation and dismissal.*"

Comment: @GlenJoyner, wxValidator is used to "validate the user input". And so if you for example set the valid string to be `abc`, and start by typing `A`, the validator will immediately fail. So instead the validator is working on the dismissal of the dialog or when the control loses focus.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Interesting. So if I have an input that I want to update other areas of code as the person types it (such as when their changes affect other calculations that they may want to see), what is the best event to work with?

Comment: @Igor The validation seems to be working great! Each keypress is validated as it happens, which is exactly what I want. I just need the value as it's being updated by the user.

Comment: @GlenJoyner, this behavior (validating on each key press) is wrong and will be removed in some future release of wxWidgets (possibly even in the one coming). The only time validation will take place is - losing focus. So I wouldn't rely on this behaviour. To answer your other question - you use wxEVT_TEXT to update stuff as the user types. But this event is shouldn't be for validation and so will be removed.

Comment: @Igor I appreciate the heads up! So if I want that specific functionality, it sounds like I will need to create my own validation in the ```wxEVT_TEXT``` event for the control and use ```wxTextCtrl::changeValue``` once validated (unless wxWidgets has another method of validation I’m unaware of).

Comment: @GlenJoyner, are you sure you need a validator? The purpose of the validating user input is to prevent a user to enter an incorrect value. So if I have a range of number [15, 20, 35, 40] as valid and the user will try to enter `1`, (s)he will not be able to as `1` is invalid input. But `1` is legitimate input as the user is not finished entering the value. I strongly advise you not to use this event for validating, unless you knopw what you are doing and have an appropriate requirements.

Comment: @Igor The goal I have is to update a set of calculations as the user inputs a number (positive integers). Only having the calculations update on losing focus is a possibility if I need to, but I would prefer the calculations to update as the text is being entered. This makes me think that ```wxEVT_TEXT``` is the only time to do that. I could validate it myself with a regex and adjust/clamp accordingly, then use ```wxTextCtrl::changeValue()``` to update the input. The only other way I can think of is creating my own event handler for a custom text control.

Comment: @GlenJoyner, well imagine the user wants to enter the number `125`. (S)he enters `1` and you perform the calculation and verify that the input is not correct because it is not a satisfactory requirement. But the number `1` is rejected because number `1` is not the right value - only `125` is. So all in all you end up with a bad calculation because the data will be rejected from the validator. Do you see the issue?

Comment: That's why I said - it is better to perform whatever you want on losing focus and leave the validation behind as making it work with the validator is tricky.

Comment: @Igor That's a great point! For my use case, this would not be an issue and after removing the validator I created my own method for verifying input while updating the calculations. So far so good! I really do appreciate all the help!